# Foundation not being recognized for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to do a simple dropdown menu in foundation with the following as a test just to get it on the page.

```html
<a data-dropdown="drop2" aria-controls="drop2" ariaexpanded="false">Has Content Dropdown</a>

<div id="drop2" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
  <p>Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome!</p>
</div>
```

I keep getting hit with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`. In the call stack, it shows `foundation.js:195` at the top of the stack.

[image: Screenshot of error.]

It looks to me like `foundation.js` is not actually being loaded properly, but seeing as this is my first app using it I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing appears to be due to a mismatch between the version of `foundation.js` you're loading and the version of the tutorial which you're following.

If you're following a [tutorial for foundation.js 5.5.3](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown.html), be sure that the script you're referencing is 5.5.3, whether that be [through a CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundation/5.5.3) or a local copy.

The error you're seeing regarding the `className` of an `undefined` was being thrown by the following line in `foundation.js` which exists in `v6.0.0` onwards.

```
var horizontalPosition = /float-(\S+)\s/.exec(this.$anchor[0].className);
```

The `$anchor` in question is a jQuery object whose selector matched any element with a `data-toggle` or `data-open` matching the `id` attribute of the dropdown content.

The API for dropdowns was different in prior versions, hence the mismatch and your error.

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a data-dropdown="drop2" aria-controls="drop2" aria-expanded="false">Has Content Dropdown</a>
<div id="drop2" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown content" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
  <p>Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome!</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just ended up following the instructions from the git of foundation-rails: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails

Comment: @scotchpasta Where did you see `data-dropdown-content` and `f-dropdown` being used in relation to 6.2.3? I've not seen that.

Comment: ...Yikes. This is entirely due to my inattentiveness. Thanks for your help :)